# How to use Xmfloat in class (Migrating from d3dx)

Tags: d3dx, directxmath

I'm trying to migrate to directxmath, but the new code is giving me some trouble..

```
 class Vec3 : public XMFLOAT3
{
public:
    inline float Length() { return XMVector3Length(this); }
    inline Vec3 *Normalize() { return static_cast<Vec3 *>(  XMVector3Normalize(this, this)); }
    inline float Dot(const Vec3 &b) { return  XMVector3Dot(this, &b); }
    inline Vec3 Cross(const Vec3 &b) const;

    Vec3(XMFLOAT3 &v3) { x = v3.x; y = v3.y; z = v3.z; }
    Vec3() : XMFLOAT3() { XMVectorZero(); }
    Vec3(const float _x, const float _y, const float _z) { x=_x; y=_y; z=_z; }
     Vec3(const double _x, const double _y, const double _z) { x = (float)_x; y = (float)_y; z = (float)_z; }
    inline Vec3(const class Vec4 &v4);
 };
```

The old code looked like:

```
 class Vec3 : public D3DXVECTOR3 
     {
    public:
        inline float Length() { return D3DXVec3Length(this); }
        inline Vec3 *Normalize() { return static_cast<Vec3 *(D3DXVec3Normalize(this, this)); }
        inline float Dot(const Vec3 &b) { return D3DXVec3Dot(this, &b); }
        inline Vec3 Cross(const Vec3 &b) const;

        Vec3(D3DXVECTOR3 &v3) { x = v3.x; y = v3.y; z = v3.z; }
        Vec3() : D3DXVECTOR3() { x = 0; y = 0; z = 0; }
        Vec3(const float _x, const float _y, const float _z) { x=_x; y=_y; z=_z; }
         Vec3(const double _x, const double _y, const double _z) { x = (float)_x; y = (float)_y; z = (float)_z; }
        inline Vec3(const class Vec4 &v4);
     };
```

So, the problem i'm getting now is that XMVector3Length cannot convert from Vec3* to _m128

Edit:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.geometric.xmvector3length.aspx
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It seems like the return type changed to a vector, with equal results instead of just a single float.

Answer (score 0):

`XMFLOAT3` does not implicitly convert to `XMVECTOR` in the [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) library. You have to use `XMLoadFloat3`.  The `Length` method above would be:

```
inline float Length() const
    { XMVECTOR v = XMLoadFloat3(this);
      return XMVectorGetX( XMVector3Length(v) ); }
```

I'd recommend taking a look at the [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) wrapper for DirectXMath in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929). It makes using these types a little more forgiving by making heavy use of C++ implicit conversions like you are assuming above. The `SimpleMath::Vector3` class is essentially what you are trying to write above. The SimpleMath version has the advantage of converting to native DirectXMath types so you can in theory make more efficient use of the SIMD than you could with your abstraction above.